# AIOGRAM: Как сделать вывод уведомления при получении текстового сообщения/команды?

Tags: python, aiogram

Возможно ли реализовать вывод подобного уведомления при получении обычного сообщения или команды, а не при нажатии кнопки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, это невозможно

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, **нет**, потому что уведомление получается так:
`answer.callback_query(callback_query.id, text='Кря', show_alert=False)`
(чтобы вылезло уведомление с кнопкой, нужно поставить `True`).

`callback_query` - ничто иное, как запрос от кнопки, от текста его получить нельзя.